# Why my android app is going back to previous activity while I fill up a simple question form to database?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build a quiz app, where admin will create questions in admin activity and these questions will be shown as quiz exam in another activity. While I try to fill up the form by clicking CREATE QUESTION button from admin activity my app is going back to previous activity(adminlogin activity)
Here is the code of AdminActivity:

```
public class AdminActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btnCreateQuestion, btnReadQuestion, btnDeleteQuestion;
EditText editTextQuestion, editTextOption1, editTextOption2, editTextOption3, editTextOption4,
    editTextAnswerNo,editTextChapterNo;
QuizDbHelper db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);
    btnCreateQuestion = findViewById(R.id.btnCreateQuestion);
    btnReadQuestion = findViewById(R.id.btnReadQuestions);
    btnDeleteQuestion = findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteQuestions);
    editTextQuestion = findViewById(R.id.editTextQuestion);
    editTextOption1 = findViewById(R.id.editTextOption1);
    editTextOption2 = findViewById(R.id.editTextOption2);
    editTextOption3 = findViewById(R.id.editTextOption3);
    editTextOption4 = findViewById(R.id.editTextOption4);
    editTextAnswerNo = findViewById(R.id.editTextAnswerNo);
    editTextChapterNo = findViewById(R.id.editTextChapterNo);
    db = new QuizDbHelper(this);

    btnCreateQuestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String question = editTextQuestion.getText().toString();
            String option1 = editTextOption1.getText().toString();
            String option2 = editTextOption2.getText().toString();
            String option3 = editTextOption3.getText().toString();
            String option4 = editTextOption4.getText().toString();
            Integer answerNo = Integer.parseInt(editTextAnswerNo.getText().toString());
            String chapterName = editTextAnswerNo.getText().toString();
            if( question != "" && option1 != "" && option2 != "" && option3 != "" && option4 != "" && answerNo!= null && chapterName != ""){
                Question q = new Question(question,option1,option2,option3,option4,answerNo,chapterName);
                db.addQuestion(q);
                Toast.makeText(AdminActivity.this,"Question Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(AdminActivity.this,"Please fill up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
    btnReadQuestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           ArrayList<Question> allQuestions = db.getAllQuestions();
           if(allQuestions.size()< 1){
                Toast.makeText(AdminActivity.this,"No questions in the Database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }else {
               StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
               for (Question q: allQuestions) {
                   buffer.append("Question : " + q.getQuestion() + "\n" );
                   buffer.append("Option1:  " + q.getOption1() + "\n");
                   buffer.append("Option2:  " + q.getOption2() + "\n");
                   buffer.append("Option3:  " + q.getOption3() + "\n");
                   buffer.append("Option4:  " + q.getOption4() + "\n");
                   buffer.append("Answer No:  " + q.getAnswerNo() + "\n");
                   buffer.append("Option4:  " + q.getChapterName() + "\n\n");
               }

               AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AdminActivity.this);
               builder.setCancelable(true);
               builder.setTitle("Questions");
               builder.setMessage(buffer.toString());
               builder.show();
           }
        }
    });
    btnDeleteQuestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}}
```

Any clue? Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Probably some of your `EditText` return `null`, Hence there is a `NullPointerException`. Check your logcat

Comment: No error in the logcat.

Comment: Try `debug` and check which causes problem

Comment: I debugged, the app is going to looper.java file from my activity file. then looping there then app is going back to previous activity. All editTexts are getting variables.

Comment: Suspecting an exception, and the **AdminActivity** is destroyed and the background **LoginActivity** showed. I would suggest to add try catch block over the onClick implementation and log the exception trace. This may help to find the exception.

Comment: I think the problem is in here:  Integer answerNo = Integer.parseInt(editTextAnswerNo.getText().toString()); Is it a correct statement?

Comment: Md. Asaduzzaman, You are right, I am getting a NullPointerExeption error, Even though every EditText getting value, I checked by debugging. What should I do,

Answer (score 1):

Check in `onCreate` function of your Activity class, did you have initialize your `EditText` and `Button`.

Also, You have to make change in your condition as below:

```
if(!question.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !option1.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !option2.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !option3.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !option4.equalsIgnoreCase("") && answerNo != 0 && !chapterName.equalsIgnoreCase("")
```

Because, `==` tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object).

Whereas, `equalsIgnoreCase()` ignores the case while comparing two strings.

Comment: Yes, I have initiated, EditTexts and Buttons.

Comment: I guess the problem is in here:Integer answerNo = Integer.parseInt(editTextAnswerNo.getText().toString()); Is it a correct statement?

Comment: In xml: make your editText inputType to number for answerNo.

Comment: Already did it, getting:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)' on a null object reference
        at com.tanvirgeek.quizeexamapp.QuizDbHelper.addQuestion(QuizDbHelper.java:98)

Comment: I fixed the problem. There were two errors:1. Null Pointer exception, because my db variable in DbHelper class was only initiated, not assigned. 2. EditText  answerNo  Integer was unable to handle "N/A" if I kept the field empty and click the insert button. Thanks everyone for taking some time here.